# d3.js setting all fill colors to stroke colors for a given selection

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js and working on a clickable legend. As part of this I want to set all legend circles fill values to its stroke values. However, this is not working as I thought. Can anybody point me to my mistake please.

Not working:

```
d3.selectAll(".legendCircle").style("fill", function(d){ return d.style("stroke");});
```

However, this is working fine:

```
d3.selectAll(".legendCircle").style("fill", function(d){ return "red";});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d3.selectAll(".legendCircle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {return d3.select(this).style("stroke")});
```

You need to specify the DOM element associated with the data, not the data itself.